# Microsoft.Office.WebExtension not working when I use the Excel JavaScript API to build an add-in

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm using the Office JS library to create an Excel add-in, and the Microsoft object is not being recognized. All the other classes from the library seem to to work fine, but when I call `dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,processMessage` the Microsoft object is not evaluated properly. This is despite every other object from this library working fine.

I'm following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial

I'm using CDN from this link: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js

The method that calls `Microsoft.Office.WebExtension` fails, and I knew it would because WebStorm tells me its not recognized.

All of the other objects from Office JS work fine though...here's an example of working code:

```
function sortTable() {
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        // Queue commands to sort the table by merchant name
        var currentWorkbook = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        var expensesTable = currentWorkbook.tables.getItem('ExpensesTable');
        var sortFields = [
            {
                key: 1,
                ascending: false,
            }
        ];
        expensesTable.sort.apply(sortFields);
        return context.sync();

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error" + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });

}
```

I've review in detail the Office JavaScript API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview

I've reviewed that there is an older common API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office?view=word-js-preview

I have suspected that I need access to this older common API, but the only documentation I've found says that you are just supposed to use the office.js library I've linked above.

Here's the whole function I'm trying to use:

```
function openDialog() {
    //Call the Office Common API that opens a dialog
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        'https://localhost:3000/popup.html',
        {height: 45, width:55},
        function (result) {
            dialog = result.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,processMessage);
        }
    )
}
```

It does in fact open a dialog box as the `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` method works. But as soon as you get to `Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived` WebStorm tells me that the element Microsoft is an unresolved reference.

And here's the function it should call if it worked, `processMessage`. Because it does not get this far, the element does not get updated, and the dialog box does not close. I'm near 100% certain the issue is not with the function below, but I'm not ruling it out yet.

```
function processMessage(arg) {
    console.log("made it inside processMessage")
    document.getElementById("user-name").innerHTML = arg.message;
    console.log("made ti just before dialog.close")
    dialog.close();
}
```

Comment: did you get to resolve this ptoblem?

Comment: I did not. I converted to Google Sheets instead.

Comment: best thing you could have done

Answer (score 0):

The full name has been shortened to Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived. Here's the GitHub issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/1710